# Mapping in Python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of index stored in a list of tuples:

```
index=[(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) ....]
```

These indexes will be used to calculate energy in an image `im` (a numpy array) in the following formula:

```
(1-im[0,0])^2+(1-im[0,1])^2+....
```

`im` here is a two dimensional numpy array. Here's an example of `im`:

```
im=Image.open('lena_noisy.png')
im=numpy.array(im)
print im

[[168 133 131 ..., 127 213 107]
 [174 151 111 ..., 191  88 122]
 [197 173 143 ..., 182 153 125]
 ..., 
 [ 34  15   6 ..., 111  95 104]
 [ 37  15  57 ..., 121 133 134]
 [ 49  39  58 ..., 115  74 107]]
```

How to use map function of list to perform this calculation?

Comment: It's a 2 dimensional numpy array, like a lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sum` and a generator expression:

```
sum(((1 - im[i[0], i[1]]) ** 2) for i in index)
```

If index is also a numpy array you can use the array as an index:

```
sum(((1 - im[i]) ** 2) for i in index)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you break `index` into two tuples, `xidx` and `yidx` then you can use fancy indexing to access all the `im` values as one numpy array.
Then the calculation becomes simple to express, and faster than doing a Python loop (or list comprehension):

```
import numpy as np
xidx, yidx = zip(*index)
print(((1-im[xidx, yidx])**2).sum())
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc as misc

im = misc.lena()
n = min(im.shape)
index = np.random.randint(n, size = (10000,2)).tolist()

def using_fancy_indexing(index, im):
    xidx, yidx = zip(*index)
    return (((1-im[xidx, yidx])**2).sum())

def using_generator_expression(index, im):
    return sum(((1 - im[i[0], i[1]]) ** 2) for i in index)
```

Here is a comparison using timeit:

```
In [27]: %timeit using_generator_expression(index, im)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit using_fancy_indexing(index, im)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.07 ms per loop
```

Thus, depending on the size of `index`, using fancy indexing could be 8x faster than using a generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, using a generator expression:

```
sum((1-im[i][j])**2 for i, j in index)
```

That is, assuming that `im` is a two-dimensional list and `index` is a list of coordinates in `im`. Notice that in Python, a two-dimensional list is accessed like this: `m[i][j]` and not like this: `m[i,j]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can unpack the tuple as part of the iteration, rather than indexing: `sum((1-im[i][j])**2 for i, j in index)`.

Comment: @Blckknght you're right, that's much clearer. I updated my answer, thanks!